# AppVeyor - Deploy only when is a tag in an specific branch

Tags: git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, appveyor

I'm trying to configure my appveyor.yml to deploy only when is a tag (annotated tag) in an specific branch. This is a fragment of my appveyor.yml:

```
  - provider: WebDeploy
    ....
    on:
      branch: appveyor-integration
      appveyor_repo_tag: true
      configuration: Production
```

I can see in the logs that AppVeyor is skipping the deployment

> Skip "WebDeploy" deployment as no branches matched (build branch is
>   "v0.0.1-alpha", deploy on branches "appveyor-integration")

Note: my tag name is ***v0.0.1-alpha***

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `branch` condition in my deploy configuration.

When branch is not sent in webhook payload it's set to tag name.

Comment: I think it's very bad design on AppVeyor's part to conflate the "tag" and "branch" concepts into one property. I would too like to only build tags on a specific branch, but since the branch name is set to the tag (which is built separately, for some reason), I don't know the name of the branch when building a tag. Sucks.